# HTML PHP input checked attribute on checkbox without submitting form

Tags: php, html, form-submit

I have a website, and on it I have a form with check-boxes to be filled. In PHP, I am wondering if there is a checked attribute which works when focus is lost on the check-box, not when the submit button us clicked. I have tried

```
    if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {

    // Checkbox is selected
    } else {

   // Alternate code
   }
```

but it only works when the submit button is clicked. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can easily achieve this with use of ajax

Comment: can you give us the html?

Comment: PHP isn't present after the page has loaded. You could do this with JS.

Comment: but there is a way to do it with php @chris85

Comment: @JackSmith not without reloading the page or using JS.

Comment: @chris85 you are right

Comment: @chris85 but they requested in php

Comment: @JackSmith user's request things all the time that aren't possible. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mqBo-9HZcOE/UWFInWe4UzI/AAAAAAAAAHg/oFnwGDbXjfA/s1600/ClientSideAjax.gif there was a better picture with a talking yellow computer but i cant find it right now

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP is a server-side script (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), there's no way to instantiate code on a client-side (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) event (such as loss of focus). To check if the checkbox is checked BEFORE the form is submitted, you will need to run a javascript/JQuery script.

For instance, you could use AJAX with JQuery to trigger the event.

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.checkbox').focusout(function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            ... 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Then you would have the `$.ajax();` function point to a PHP script to execute whatever you need done.

You can find more here:

1. `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
2. `focusout()`: https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with use of ajax. Fire a function when user `interact`

```
<input type='checkbox' onblur='checkbox()' />

function checkbox(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "checkbox.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

Using `onblur` wont give you the desired results try changing it to different `events` see which matches your need

Here is the [list](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) of all events in `HTML DOM EVENT`